# blade отображение справа налево

Tags: php, laravel

Вывожу продукт с помощью `@foreach($roots as $root)` - в итоге вывод получатся справа налево - есть ли способ сделать наоборот ?

ps :пробовал сортировать по `id` (`orderBy...`) / вывести через `for/` но не в `id` тут дело..

Comment: может вам шаблон нужно поправить, а не данные

Comment: Спаасибо )))
я совсем забыл - попробовал fllexbox  в проЭкте, а он по умолчанию справа на лево выводит данные )) 
вообщем поправил :     flex-direction:rtl;
Еще раз спс ..

Answer (score 0):

В шаблоне использовал flexbox - а у него вывод по умолчанию справа на лево .
Поправил flex-direction:rtl;
Спасибо Лене )